# invoking blazor server controller method from (.Client) WASM project

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I am working on a .net8 Blazor project using the interactive auto template, which contains both server and client projects in the same solution. In the server project, I have folders “Models” and “Controllers.” Now, I want to make an HTTP client call from my Blazor client project to a controller in the server project.

I tried adding a reference to myServerProject.Server inside myClientProject.Client, but it’s not getting added. Can someone provide a clear and concise example of how to set up this reference correctly and make an HTTP client call from the Blazor client project to a controller in the server project?

Comment: You can't reference a server project from a client project.  They are incompatible.  You need to put all the shared code, your data objects etc, in a shared library that you reference from both.

Comment: Curious if you're familiar with the primary distinction between calling a method in a registered controller class versus triggering an `http.SendJsonAsync` from the client browser.

Comment: we have [blazor samples here](https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples/blob/main/8.0/BlazorWebAppOidc/MinimalApiJwt/Program.cs). as you can see in this sample, we have minmal API `app.MapGet("/weatherforecast",` in a seperate project, then in the client project, it doesn't add a reference for the minimal API, but to send a http request. I'm afraid you scenario is similar. When we use auto render mode, the pages/components in the  client project are using client side render, which worked like SPA, so that we should send http request to call API.

Comment: That’s not quite what I asked for. We can register a controller using addScoped then inject it in one of the razor views and use to call whatever methods defined there, also we could use http to invoke the controller (/api/controller/method). My question is what is the key difference between both ways.

Comment: I'm curious about how can we `register a controller using addScoped`.. I searched about it but no luck, could you please share some document? In my humble opinion, when we we use DI to inject some services into controller, we are trying to call some method to handle data inside our web application(server side) then we could return data in controller. If we `use http to invoke the controller`, that means we are hitting the server from a client or another server to get some data. Key differences between both ways,,,, I think they are completely 2 different things.

Comment: By the way, have you succeed to add a reference to myServerProject.Server from myClientProject.Client ?? I'm curious about it. Per my understanding, the Client project should work like a SPA, but the server project worked in Server, so it shouldn't work, so can we call it a "way"? Please correct me if I misunderstood it. Thanks in advance. I want to know how to do that if you know it.

Comment: VS let you select it when right-click on client project reference but nothing is added. I believe the only way is have the models/controllers shared in a 3rd project as @MrCakaShaunCurtis suggested. I will share some code once I get access to my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I reference a server project in a client project?

The issue is that any project built with the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK uses libraries that are incompatible with the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly` SDK.

Normally you reference the Client project in the Server project, so you can't  create a circular reference.

If you remove that reference, and then add one to the client, you will get this error:

```
NETSDK1082  There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.
```

The solution is to move all the components, data objects and services to a `Shared` project that uses the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` SDK.  You then reference this project from the Client and Server projects.

Think of *Server* and *Client* as deployment projects. *Shared* is a resource.  Most of the code lives in *Shared*.  The deployment projects just contain code and configuration data specific to the deployment.